# How to take effect `usermod` command without logout and login

Tags: fedora

I'm using fedora19, and I've added `wheel` to my account like this.

`usermod -a -G wheel ironsand`

And I've logged out and logged in again to take effect the command according to the following answer.
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/9769/sofia-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file/

I don't need to restart when I change `.bashrc`, if I use `source` command.
Is there no way to take `usermod` effect likewise?

Comment: You don't need to log out to login. Running `su <username>` is sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Careful where you draw your analogies. The sourcing of the `.bashrc` can be dangerous in the sense that if a variable is being added to you'll get into the situation where something like this can occur:

*initial env*

```
PATH=/path/to/dir
```

*sourced env*

```
PATH=/path/to/dir:/path/to/dir
```

That's why it's generally a good practice to logout and log back in when fundamental changes are made to low level environment files such as `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`.

Being added to or removed from Unix groups should also be viewed as a major change, requiring a logout/login.

You can get some access, at least in a single shell, by also doing one of these 3 operations with respect to the Unix group changing showing up:

- `su - <user>`
- `su <user>`
- `newgrp`

The 3rd method will work, but it will require you to blindly change your self to a group that doesn't show up yet in your existing environment, and will then make your primary group this new group, which may not be what you want.

#### Why

If you take a look at the man page, [credentials](http://linux.die.net/man/7/credentials) you'll see why child processes cannot have changes made via `usermod` immediately reflected in a real-time way:

*excerpt*

> A child process created by fork(2) inherits copies of its parent's
>   user and groups IDs. During an execve(2), a process's real user and
>   group ID and supplementary group IDs are preserved; the effective and
>   saved set IDs may be changed, as described in execve(2).